# how to define a GEV (generalized extreme value) distribution to a copula?

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a copula for two variables which have extreme value distribution. for "mvdc" class, I need to define margins and parammargins. Since GEV is not included in default distribution functions of Rcopula, I got these two values by using "evd" package, by these two functions:

```
# pgev gives the Generalized Extreme Value distribution function
GEVmarginU1<-pgev(U1, loc=0, scale=1, shape=0, lower.tail = TRUE)
GEVmarginV2<-pgev(V2, loc=0, scale=1, shape=0, lower.tail = TRUE)

#fit a generalised extreme value distribution to my data 
MU1 <- fgev(U1, scale = 1, shape = 0)
MV2 <- fgev(V2, scale = 1, shape = 0)
```

but when I give these values to "mvdc" function, I get an error

```
myMvd <- mvdc(copula = ellipCopula(family = "Frank", param = 0), margins = c(pgev, pgev),
         paramMargins = list(list(MU1), list(MV2))
```

Most importantly, I want to be sure whether I am in a right track. Since two variables are obtained from discrete choice model, I have extreme value distribution. Also the marginal have GEV distribution, right? So I need to define GEV for "mvdc" otherwise my fitted copula will not wok well.

```
(1)  Ui = β1Xi1 + β2Xi2 + β3Xi3 + εi
(2)  Vi = γ1Yj1 + γ2Yj2 + γ3Yj3 + ηi
```

in summary:

```
(1)  Ui = β'Xi' + εi
(2)  Vi = γ'Yj' + ηi
```

Since these models are made from discrete choice modelling approach, the distribution function follows “extreme value” distribution. First step: I estimate coefficients of β1,β2,β3,γ1,γ2,γ3 separately for each variable of i and Vj by using multinomial logit model using Biogeme software. But intuitively I know that they are dependent variables, so I try to fit a copula and again estimate coefficients by considering dependency value. So, the joint probability that Ui and Vi is chosen by decision-maker n is:
[image]

These marginals are transformed to continuous, but still have extreme value distribution, am I right?!???

1) How can I define GEV when using “mvdc” copula class in Rcopula?

Second, assume I used “fitcopula” instead of “mvdc”, and got param(dependency parameter of copula), if I understood correctly, “fitcopula” is for parametric and in my case, it’s non-parametric, am I right?

2) Now, how should I update coefficients by using a joint distribution and dependency parameter???

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, I found out that my marginals are logistic randomly distributed, since they are the difference between two error terms in the utility model and we know that error terms follow type 1 extreme value or Gumbel distribution, and the difference between two Gumbel distribution follow logistics distribution, according to the Wikipedia.